# How to get started with Simulation and UC proofs?

Tags: provable-security, multiparty-computation, security-definition, universal-composability, simulation

I've been in my PhD program for a few months, and every time I try to understand the simulation and UC proof-paradigms I get so confused.

I feel like what I really need is an easy set of (guided) problems and examples that I can play around with and try to prove, starting with non-composable simulation and then moving up to UC. Something that would help me train this muscle so this becomes more intuitive.

Does something like that exist? How does one overcome this hurdle?

Comment: [How to Simulate It](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046) ?

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of this paper and did not find it very digestable as it claims to be. I'm hoping for (and quite surprised if there aren't) any other resources

Comment: I learned with the book of Ivan, Jesper and Ronald: Secure multiparty computation. Cambridge University Press, 2015. The first few sections contain simplified protocols and their definitions, although full fledged and formal, are much easy to digest (IMO) than 'How to Simulate It' and also the original UC papers